# django / javascript / jquery / html / css: summing the contents of a form for display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I'm going to build a django form for a web page that will allow the user to input two numbers:

```
    <form action="blah" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    number1:
    <input type="number" name="number1" value="{{ number1 }}" />
    number2:
    <input type="number" name="number2" value="{{ number2 }}" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Elsewhere on the page, I'd like to display the product of these two numbers as a user enters them. What's the most efficient way to do that?

---

EDIT(2): I was able to get everything working with a slight modification of the code provided:

```
{% if [test] %} 


<div style="padding-top: 10%; padding-left: 12%">
    <div class="row-fluid" >
        <div class="span10 hero-unit" >

         ...

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{%  else %}

<div style="padding-top: 10%; padding-left: 20%;">
    <div class="row-fluid" style="vertical-align: middle">
        <div class="span8 hero-unit">

            ...

            <form action="/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if next %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                {% endif %}
                <div class="question"><<Question1>>
                <input type="number" class="pull-right" name = "question1" value="{{ question1 }}" />
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="question"><<Question2>>
                <input type="number" class="pull-right" name="question2" value="{{ question2 }}" />
                </div>
                <br>
                <div style="padding-right: 10%">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button-text pull-right" value="Submit" />
                </div>
                <div id="product_output_container" style="padding-left: 10%;font-weight: bold" ></div>

                <br>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endif %}

<!-- jquery -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
            function(){

                var refreshProduct = function(){

                    var question1 = parseInt($('[name="question1"]').val(),10);
                    var question2 = parseInt($('[name="question2"]').val(),10);

                    var product = question1 * question2;

                    var product_container = $('#product_output_container');
                    if (!isNaN(product)){
                        product_container.text(product)
                    }
                    else{
                        product_container.text("")
                    }
                }

                $('[name="question1"]').keyup(refreshProduct);
                $('[name="question2"]').keyup(refreshProduct);
            }
    );
</script>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you saving it because your using post? or just searching a product?

Comment: $(document).ready
requires a function (callback) as first parameter

and of course as aidan pointed out below by adding the number input .output you did break his query selector which is why you should query these items by something unique you can specify such as name, class or id

Answer (score 0):

Attach a jquery keyup event to each of your inputs. Have the event multiply the two inputs and put the total in your output element.

```
$('form input.pull-right').keyup(function() {
    var $inputs = $('form input.pull-right');
    var product = 1;
    for (var i = $inputs.length; i > 0; i--) {
        product *= parseInt($inputs[i].val());
    }
    $('form input.output').val(total);
}
```

Here's the docs on jquery's [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Incidentally this code will work if you add more inputs (of class pull-right). The code loops through them all..

Comment: You've added an output where type=number. That breaks my selector. i'll update my code.

Comment: Do read the jquery docs on how selectors work - http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

if its just the product of 2 numbers you can do

```
var refreshProduct = function(){
$('#product_output_container').val(parseInt($('[name="number1"]').val(),10)*parseInt($('[name="number2"]').val(),10));
}
$('[name="number1"]').keyup(refreshProduct);
$('[name="number2"]').keyup(refreshProduct);
```

if its getting more complex you should consider using a templating lib like knockout.js

here is a working example:

```
            <form>

                <input type="number" name="question1" />

                <input type="number" name="question2" />


                <input type="number" class="output"/>
            </form>




<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        refreshProduct = function(){
            $('.output').val(parseInt($('[name="question1"]').val(),10)*parseInt($('[name="question2"]').val(),10));
        }

        $('[name="question1"]').keyup(refreshProduct);
        $('[name="question2"]').keyup(refreshProduct);
    });
</script>
```